# Declaring an anonymous tuple with using; is it possible?

Tags: c#

```
using Coordinate = (int x, int y);
```

does not compile.

```
using Coordinate = System.Tuple<int, int>;
```

does compile.

Due to reasons I prefer the former; can it be done?

**UPDATE:**

The reason has been questioned and debated so here is why:

I have a small class that works with a tuple. I could write a small tuple `class Coord{int x; int y;}` but decided not to. Instead I wrote `(int x, int y)` everywhere and let the duck typing do its magic. It works alright but in some places impedes readability, possibly because we are *trained* in reading types as `PascalCase` and not `(pare,the,sised)`.
So I had the idea that, just like giving the type `Tuple<int,int>`an alias I could give the anonymous type `(int x, int y)` an alias. Then I could use the alias or the anonymous type depending on what I decide is more readable.
(my real code is slighly more complicated than x&y)

Comment: The first one makes no sense given the context (i.e a namespace alias).  You wouldn't deal with variable names in a namespace alias, I am not even sure why you would want this or what it would solve...

Comment: And if you just want to use an alias for [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netframework-4.7.2), just use the namespace:`using Coordinate = System.ValueTuple<int, int>;`.  The `( ... )` syntax is not valid in that context so you have to actually use the namespace

Comment: Due to **what** reasons?

Comment: I think, this is similar issue to why you can't set default value on optional string argument to `string.empty`, it wants `""`. The first tuple is syntactic sugar. There is not type there yet. `Using` directive requires known type or namespace.

Comment: `(int x, int y)` is short-hand for `ValueTuple<int, int>`, but *with* meta-data about the names for the two tuple items. It is a perfect legal request, but the compiler doesn't support it, because the support hasn't been added.

Comment: @T.S. I believe your comment is the most informative. "The first tuple is syntactic sugar." I have found no such information though (google skillz?) If you can link to such information and write an Answer I will mark it as so. TIA.

Comment: *"Finally, one last remark about the names of tuple members: like many other language features, they’re just syntactic sugar. In the compiled code, the tuple members are only referred to as Item1 and Item2, not count and sum."* https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2016/07/25/tuples-in-c-7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 things to pay attention to

1. `using` directive requires a known namespace or type
2. When tuple declared as `(int x, int y) t = ...` you only have compiler command but not type.

If you declared variable as tuple compiler will generate something like this

```
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TupleElementNames(new string[] {"x", "y"})]
System.ValueTuple<int, int> myVar = ...
```

We are talking here of syntactic sugar that makes use of tuple easier and named items available at design time with real types being generated at compile time. But certain directives, etc. require a known type. Hence you have the issue importing type that does not exist.

[Check this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt493248.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

No the former can not be used, since it's no valid C# syntax.

Even though `using Coordinate = System.Tuple<int, int>;` compiles, i'd like to propose a different approach to what you are probably trying to achieve:

```
public class Coordinate
{
    public Coordinate(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}

var coordinate = new Coordinate(xVariable, yVariable);
```

You can than access your `X` and `Y` varibale via `coordinate.X` or `coordinate.Y`.

As pointed out by [maccettura](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2457029/maccettura) i should include my reasoning for this approach:

1. If you are trying to change a Coordinate later on Tuple would be limiting you, since its Items can't be modified after Creation
2. Furthermore i thought you might want to add some more functionality to your Coordinate, e.g. with a `ToString()` or other Methods/Properties

Comment: OP is talking about `using` _directives_ not `using` _statements_

Comment: @maccettura i believe Tuple would be limiting OP in the long run, since he can't write to the Tuple Items after creating them. Maybe he wants to extend the functionality of his Coordinates later on by adding Methods and what not to it. He can still choose to make Coordinate a struct if he cares about it being not a reference type.

Comment: _Not_ being able to modify it may actually be a desirable feature. For something like a coordinate it makes sense that you shouldn't be able to change it. It should be immutable. Just like a number isn't, itself, mutable. You can't change a literal int to another number, instead you replace it. I agree using a struct (or _maybe_ a class) with read-only properties might be useful, but probably not because of the potential to mutate it.

Comment: @MattBurland Of course you are right on this. But it all remains in mystery, since OP hasn't given any clues on what he's trying to do with it, i just answered his question about the syntax and decided to add a little something to show him that what he's trying to do can be done without using a Tuple.

Comment: `ValueTuple<...>` is not immutable.

Comment: As for not giving any clues, he said he wanted to avoid typing in `(int x, int y)` all over the place and instead use a name for it. Also a perfectly legal request, but if you care enough about your tuples and anymous objects that they should have a name to identify them, use a proper named type already (like this answer provides).